# Usage of allenai/bilm-tf for Q&A

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I am trying to use [allenai/bilm-tf](https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf) for Q&A and tried to get results from [usage_character.py](https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf/blob/master/usage_character.py), but i do not understand how to continue from this example.

```py
raw_context = [
    'Pretrained biLMs compute representations useful for NLP tasks .',
    'They give state of the art performance for many tasks .'
]
tokenized_context = [sentence.split() for sentence in raw_context]
tokenized_question = [
    ['What', 'are', 'biLMs', 'useful', 'for', '?'],
]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # It is necessary to initialize variables once before running inference.
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Create batches of data.
    context_ids = batcher.batch_sentences(tokenized_context) #shape: [2, 11, 50]
    question_ids = batcher.batch_sentences(tokenized_question)

    # Compute ELMo representations (here for the input only, for simplicity).
    elmo_context_input_, elmo_question_input_ = sess.run(
        [elmo_context_input['weighted_op'], elmo_question_input['weighted_op']],
        feed_dict={context_character_ids: context_ids,
                   question_character_ids: question_ids})
```

The output sess.run() returns confuses me, because I expected a 2d array with probabilities/logits to perform argmax on to get a span for tokenized_context, which is my answer. But this is not the case. The shape of elmo_context_input_ is [2, 11, 32].

My Questions are now:

- Do I need to perform additional prediction steps (bc the author mentioned: "here for the input only, for simplicity")
- How do I project the output back on the original text and/or the vocabulary file to receive my answer

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue?

Comment: No, sadly i haven't.